# Selecting every Nth row, Excel. Replace with nothing or original cell content

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've got an Excel sheet with my variables listed in column `E` and their values listed in column `G`

I would like to test if `E` contains the word `"text"` (my variable). If so then I want to replace the corresponding cell in column `G` with `"This is my successful if statement text"`.

If not -- I want the cell to either be left alone (impossible in excel) or keep the value it originally had (I think the issue is its populated with text not numbers).

So far ive tried

```
=if(e2="text", "Replace with this", G2)
```

as well as

```
=if(e2="text", "replace with this", "")
```

The top returns a number while the bottom returns an empty cell which deletes the contents I had there.

Any suggestions? I think this can be done with VB but that's out of my league.

Comment: You cannot use a formula to replace a value in another cell - a formula only returns a value.  You would have to use a different column to place your formula.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean? I can replace the value by testing for an condition and giving it a value if its met..

Comment: You write: `then I want to replace the corresponding cell in column G with 'This is my successful if statement text'` - I read that as wanting to replace a value in another cell.  Where are you entering your formula?

Comment: In column E I have four possible values, 'description_tag', 'title_tag', 'headline', 'text'. In column G I have different text for each of those variables depending what product it is. The value for 'text' is either blank or 'You're one click away from....". In G2 is where I'm placing the formula and trying to drag it down. It works for those where 'text' is the variable but for all the others, 'headline' etc.. it replaces the cell with nothing (which is what excel is supposed to do -- but I dont want it to) So really need a workaround..

Comment: So essentially every 4th row contains the word 'text' in column E and has a string I want to replace in column G

Comment: A cell contain either a value or a formula - when you enter a formula in a cell you over-write its value.  So you need to enter your formula in (eg) ColH

Comment: If I enter my formula in a different column, how do I get the solution to populate in the right cell..

Comment: You'll have to copy then `pastespecial >> values`

Comment: Or set it equal to the formula column?

Comment: Idk.. seems to be a relatively hard task in excel lol! Guess we'll just chalk that one up as impossible though it should be really easy hah

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to solve this is as so.

In column H (or any that doesn't contain any information) place the formula

```
=IF(E2 = "text", "This is the true part", G2) and drag down.
```

This will test E2 for the word "text" and then replace with "this is true.." If the conditions are not met, the original text from G2 is pulled into the new column.

Once this is complete, the desired results should have taken effect. You can then copy the row and use "Paste Special" and select "Values" from the pop up menu to paste in your new data. Selecting Values allows the user to paste the actual field data, not the formula that generated it!

Comment: I don't think you understand Tim or I :/ Not sure how else to articulate it. Tim was pretty clear XD

Comment: Tim definitely has the solution but not the means to articulate it.. Your post wasn't helpful.

Comment: I think your cursory knowledge is hindering your understanding :/ To elaborate, put the formula in H2 and set G2 to equal H2. Drag both columns down. Make sense?

Comment: Your answer is correct in general excel terms but not to my problem. No matter where I put the formula, if the true conditions are not met, its going to replace the cell in column G with a blank cell, a 0, or #false. It will never just leave the text that was already there. Regardless where I put the formula......

Comment: That's odd. Your first formula is correct. So I am missing something. Please clarify your issue again. Or perhaps provide examples?

Comment: I believe @findwindow and Tim were correct, I apologize for not seeing it earlier. A more detailed description would have helped myself and those viewing this thread in the future. I have edited my solution to be that descriptive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub g()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change sheet name as applicable
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
With ws
If .Cells(i, 5) = "text" Then
.Cells(i, 7) = "The text you want"
End If
End With
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to get four values from column E that you want to parse (cut up) and place in Column G.

By creating four parses { =mid(e2,16,10), =mid(e3, 9, 15), =mid(e4,5,3), =mid(e5,10,22) } in cells G2, G3, G4, and G5, respectively, you can select the block of four G cells (G2:G5), select the block at the bottom right, and drag it down throughout the file.

Optionally, you can use modulo math and case statements to loop through the file and perform the required function at each point:

```
myCount = 0
myLoop = 0
endMyLoop = false
range("G2").activate
do
     myLoop = myCount mod 4
     select case myLoop
         case 0 
               code for description_tag
         case 1
               code for title_tag
         case 2
               code for headline
         case 3
               code for text
     end select
     if activecell.value = "" then endMyLoop = true
loop until (endMyLoop = true)
```

You stated that every fourth row the value in E is text. So, it should just be a matter of copying the formula every fourth row or performing your function every fourth iteration (modulo returns the remainder) in the G column.

One other option would be to nest your if loops (=if(e2="text","Its text",if(e2="title_tag","Its a title",if(e2="headline","Its headline","Its description")))) to account for the four different options. Of course you would fill the text with the function that you actually want to perform.